# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mousetrap' in angular 11

Tags: angular

I encounter the error when I am trying to take build of ionic. I also Upgraded my angular version of the project to the angular current version.

Error: ./node_modules/angular-modal-gallery/**ivy_ngcc**/angular-modal-gallery.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mousetrap' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ionicmatrimonial\node_modules\angular-modal-gallery_*ivy_ngcc*_'

My package.json file

````
  "name": "startapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "angular-modal-gallery": "^5.7.1",
    "angular-mousetrap-service": "^0.1.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "har-validator": "^5.1.3",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "igniteui-angular": "^7.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "mousetrap": "~1.5.3",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.1.13",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-select-ex": "^3.6.7",
    "ngx-show-hide-password-app": "git+https://github.com/osahner/ngx-show-hide-password.git",
    "ngx-spinner": "^6.1.2",
    "npm": "^7.6.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.6",
    "swiper": "^3.4.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.6",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.1.1",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/mousetrap": "^1.5.34",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}```
````

Comment: You just throw an error without any explanation and expect people to help ?

Comment: I am trying to to take build the angular app via ionic, while trying the command "ionic serve" I encounter the error.

Comment: Please edit your question and be more verbose so people can help. You can add your package.json file and steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: Did you try removing the node_modules and installing it again ?

Comment: I tried it many times, but still got the same error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now its working fine.